# Block data withing range of date

Tags: go-ethereum

I need to get access to the blocks between 7000 and 8000 and since I plan to query the states I need archieve option. Do I need to run a arhieve node and wait until it downloads everything, or is there any other way to get just that time frame?

Answer (score 0):

You can query connecting to the network without having to download the full node and looping until reaching the desired results.

Another approach would be to use some already existing solutions. I found ***[this
article](https://www.anyblockanalytics.com/blog/query-ethereum-with-sql/)*** which explains how to query the Ethereum blockchain using SQL. It requires you to register, but seems to be free.

**NOTICE:** I haven't personally used or tested this solution, this is just the result of doing some research

---

**More research:**
I also found this interesting paper which proposes an EQL (Ethereum Query Language) and has a github repo, but haven't seen it working:

- Paper: https://rmod.inria.fr/archives/papers/Braga18b-WETSEB-Query.pdf
- Github Repo: https://github.com/smartanvil/UQLL